# What is the best way to get parent model data in serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
Company(DateTimeModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

Contract(DataTimeModel):
    ...
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I want to create a contract I want to send only company id

For example my input:

```
{
  "some_fields": "foo",
  ...,
  "company": 1
}
```

But in output I want to get id and title

```
{
  "id": 1,
  ...,
  "company": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "company title",
  }
}
```

This is my serializer:

```
class ContractSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    company = CompanyRelatedSerializer(read_only=True)
```

But I should create validation for company_id manualy and it is two different fields.

I guess there is a better implementation than mine. How do it better?

Comment: What you have is how I would do it.

Comment: @schillingt Thank you for your response. But what about company_id validation? Should I create manualy validation (e.g. case when company_id doen't exists (if not Company.objects.filter(pk=attrs.get("company_id"),).exists() ... raise ValidationError) or I should use another serializer field instead of IntegerField?

Comment: You could try using a PrimaryKeyRelatedField for easier validation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield